# R function equivalent to Stata's "do" command that can run multiple programs at once?

Tags: r

I have multiple R script files that perform different types of modifications to my dataset for analysis. I'm continuously updating/adding new data to my dataset and re-running each individual program is somewhat arduous, so I'm wondering if there's an equivalent to Stata's "do" command that can run multiple R programs from one R program. For example, I have a Stata file that looks like:

```
do "\\filepath\filename.do"
do "\\filepath\filename.do"
do "\\filepath\filename.do"
do "\\filepath\filename.do"
do "\\filepath\filename.do"
```

I'd like to be able to do the same thing in R that runs multiple R programs, like:

```
r function("filepath\filename.R")
r function("filepath\filename.R")
r function("filepath\filename.R")
r function("filepath\filename.R")
```

I have searched for a solution to no avail, and perhaps I don't know the exact jargon for this type of command. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to do it from R, use can use:

```
source("path_to_file_1.R")
source("path_to_file_2.R")
```

If from outside of R (e.g. a bash script, etc.)

```
Rscript path_to_file_1.R
Rscript path_to_file_2.R
```